# How to set 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' based on mysite.settings from a different directory

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project which works good. My `manage.py` and `mysite` folder (the one that includes the following:

```
__init__.py
settings.py
urls.py
views.py
wsgi.py
```

) and a bunch of `django app` folders are located in the following directory

```
E:\mydjangoproject
```

In order to use the `django setting` of this project in a script, I used to use the following code at the beginning of that script:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
```

which always works fine since the python script file which I was running was also located in the directory `E:\mydjangoproject` and it locates the `mysite` folder as a `module` and its `settings` perfectly.
My question is what if I am trying to run that exact python script from another directory say `E:\mydjangoproject\SubFolder 1\SubFolder 2\` and still want the

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
```

Off course when I try this I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'`. How can I pass the right path of the `django settings` to the script?

Comment: You could add the scripts location to the path. `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(__file__))`

Comment: I tried adding `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(__file__)+'/SubFolder 1/SubFolder 2\')` to the `settings.py` file but nothing changed. Where should I add the path?

Comment: Don't append the subfolders, you want the location of `manage.py` to be in the path so that you can import relative to that directory

Comment: I am sorry but I dont understand how that could work! If I add this `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(__file__))` to settings.py then what does it have to do with the script in another subfodler understanding where to find the mysite.settings?

Comment: I got it. Thanks. That was a really nice hint